# counting inversions with merge sort gives a negative number if the array's length is 100000

Tags: java, mergesort

i am still a beginner at programming and i am taking an online course (algorithms)

one of the practice questions was to count the number of inversions in a file containing 100000 numbers randomly ordered

so this is my code

```
    package algo_inversion;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Algo_inversion {
    public static int splitMerge(int[]A,int start,int mid,int finish){
        int count=0;
        int []L=new int[mid+2-start];
        int []R=new int[finish-mid+1];
        System.arraycopy(A, start, L, 0, L.length-1);
        L[L.length-1]=5000000;//infinity

        for(int i=0;i<R.length-1;i++){
            R[i]=A[mid+1+i];
        }
        R[R.length-1]=5000000;//infinity

        int x=0;
        int y=0;
        for(int k=start;k<finish+1;k++){
            if(L[x]<=R[y]){
                A[k]=L[x];
                x++;
            }
            else{
                A[k]=R[y];
                y++;
                count+=L.length-1-x;
            }
        }
        return count;        
    }
    public static int countMerge(int []A,int start, int finish){
        if(finish<=start){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            int mid=(finish+start)/2;
                int leftCount=countMerge(A,start,mid);
                int rightCount=countMerge(A,mid+1,finish);
                int splitCount=splitMerge(A,start,mid,finish);
                return(leftCount+rightCount+splitCount);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int []a=new int[100001];
       Scanner in= new Scanner(new FileReader("IntegerArray.txt"));
       int i=0;
        while(in.hasNext()){
            a[i]=in.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println("inversions=: "+countMerge(a, 0, i-1));

    }
}
```

i tried it on random arrays of sizes from 1 to 200 and it works perfectly
but with the array from the file it gives me a negative number!!!
i just cant figure out what's causing that and would appreciate any help i can get 
^_^

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting the right number for 200 items? It looks like you've got some double-counting going on, so the result erroneously exceeds `2^31` limit for 32-bit integers.

Comment: yes any array smaller in size than 100000 gives the right answer

my problem is with the array of length 100000 (which is the array the practice quistion provided) it gives a wrong answer

Comment: What I found helpful when I was learning programming was using the debugger to see what my program is doing. A debugger allows you to set a breakpoint and inspect the code to see the actual values of the variables while the program is paused. Are you using an IDE? It probably has a debugger built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worst-case number of inversions in an array of size `N` is `N*(N-1)/2`. The highest value that fits in an int is roughly 2 billion, so arrays of size greater than `65,000` run a chance of overflowing an `int`, making the result look negative.

You should switch to `long` to extend the range of values representable by the counter:

```
public static long splitMerge(int[]A,int start,int mid,int finish) {
    long count = 0;
    ...
}
public static long countMerge(int []A,int start, int finish) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> i tried it on random arrays of sizes from 1 to 200 and it works perfectly but with the array from the file it gives me a negative number!!!

The number of inversions appears to exceed the value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and so you're seeing overflow into negative numbers; you should use `long` to count the number of inversions.

This is an example of Joel Spolsky's [The Perils of JavaSchools](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/ThePerilsofJavaSchools.html). By hiding people from what's really going in the machine, they don't know what's happening when they encounter issues like this. When you are counting something, and you see negative results, the *first* thing that should pop into your head is overflow, exceeded the bounds of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.